# How to remove unwanted element

Tags: javascript, validation

I'm trying to write easy validation code and I have trouble. I've created element div '._error-alert' and I cant remove it if the input isn't empty.
When I press submit appears my element '._error-alert' but it doesnt disapear when I try to type something there. I'll be very grateful if u help or at least show me the other path to solve it

[image]

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.validation__form'),
  reqItems = document.querySelectorAll('._req'),

  emailTest = /^(([^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@(([^<>()\.,;\s@\"]+\.{0,1})+[^<>()\.,;:\s@\"]{2,})$/,
  onlyTextTest = /^[a-zA-Z0-9@]+$/,
  onlyNums = /^[0-9]+$/;

const inputTest = (example, input) => example.test(input.value);

const formAddError = (input) => {
  if (input.classList.contains('_req')) {
    const createBlock = document.createElement('div');
    createBlock.classList.add('_error-alert');
    input.parentElement.insertAdjacentElement("beforeend", createBlock);
    createBlock.innerText = `Invalid ${input.getAttribute("name")}!`;
  }

  input.parentElement.classList.add('_error');
  input.classList.add('_error');

};


const formRemoveError = (input) => {
  input.parentElement.classList.remove('_error');
  input.classList.remove('_error');
};

// validates form if function validateForm didn't have any errors and removes my created elements '._error-alert'
const sendValidatedForm = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();

  let error = validateForm(form);
  if (error === 0) {
    console.log('fine');
    form.reset();
    document.querySelectorAll('._error-alert').forEach((errorAlert) => {
      errorAlert.remove();
    });
  }
};

form.addEventListener('submit', sendValidatedForm);

// there I want to check input and remove '._error-alert' if input isnt wrong
const checkInput = () => {
  reqItems.forEach((reqInput, index) => {
    reqInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
      formRemoveError(reqInput);

    });
  });
};
checkInput();

const validateForm = (form) => {
  let error = 0;

  reqItems.forEach(reqInput => {
    reqInput.value.trim();
    formRemoveError(reqInput);

    if (reqInput.getAttribute("name") == "email") {
      if (!inputTest(emailTest, reqInput)) {
        formAddError(reqInput);
        error++;
      }
    } else if (reqInput.getAttribute("name") == "phone") {
      if (!inputTest(onlyNums, reqInput) && reqInput.value.length < 8) {
        formAddError(reqInput);
        error++;
      }
    } else if (reqInput.getAttribute("name") == "name") {
      if (!inputTest(onlyTextTest, reqInput)) {
        formAddError(reqInput);
        error++;
      }
    }
  });

  console.log(error);
  return error;

};
```

```html
<form action="" class="validation__form">
  <div class="validation__input-list">
    <div class="validation__input-item">
      <input type="text" class="validation__input-input _req" name="name" placeholder="Name">
    </div>
    <div class="validation__input-item">
      <input type="text" class="validation__input-input" name="surname" placeholder="Surname">
    </div>
    <div class="validation__input-item">
      <input type="text" class="validation__input-input _req" name="phone" placeholder="Phone">
    </div>
    <div class="validation__input-item">
      <input type="text" class="validation__input-input _req" name="email" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
    <div class="validation__input-item">
      <input type="text" class="validation__input-input" name="password" placeholder="Password">
    </div>
  </div>
  <button class="validation__form-btn">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the css `visibility` property of the element to `hidden`.

```
const error_element = document.getElementsByClassName('_error-alert')
error_element.style.visibility = 'hidden'
```

Comment: You're trying to set a style for the HTMLCollection returned by getElementsByClassName there, you need to do it on the actual element: `error_element[0].style...`(resp. loop over them, if there's more than one.)